# Calling a list from a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function

For some reason, when I try to use a list from a function, calling it outside the function it doesn't work. Can anyone identify the problem here and hopefully remedy it?

```
import itertools
from itertools import izip_longest

def go():
    first =  [1,2,3,4,5,1]
    return first

go()

second = [6,7,8,9,10]

print map(sum, izip_longest(go().first, second, fillvalue=0))
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have error messages (if any occur) and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the function, you are returning the list in your function so by simply calling it you get the list:

```
print map(sum, izip_longest(go(), second, fillvalue=0))


In [4]: def go():
   ...:         first =  [1,2,3,4,5,1]
   ...:         return first
   ...: 

In [5]: go()
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

To do what you are trying to do can actually be done it would just be a lot different and not really recommended:

```
def go():
    go.first = [1,2,3,4,5,1]
    return go


second = [6,7,8,9,10]

print map(sum, izip_longest(go().first, second, fillvalue=0))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. If I had multiple lists being returned by go() and I wanted to select one of them this would be the method. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: If you want that kind of attribute lookup  a class would be better

Answer (score 0):

`go()` is a function, not a class. Go doesn't have attributes like a class, it just takes something in, and returns something else, everything in between is a "black box".

So

```
print map(sum, izip_longest(go(), second, fillvalue)
```

also a better opiton would be that you actually assign the result of your function somewhere.

```
first = go()
second = [1,2,3,4]
print first, second
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions return a value (or alter an object, or both) and that's it. While they do have members you can access (Thanks @Jon Clements), like other objects, it's not the typical way they're used, and `first` is not one of them, so `go().first` is not going to work.

Also, `go()` will give you the function's return value and not the functinos itself. So you're actually calling:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,1].first
```

Which also makes no sense.

So, `go()` returns the value that was named `first` in the function's context (that's the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`). You can use that value by giving it a name after invoking the function to get it:

```
# give `go`'s result a name
lst = go()
# now use it via that name ...
print map(sum, izip_longest(lst, second, fillvalue=0)
```

You could also use it immediately:

```
print map(sum, izip_longest(go(), second, fillvalue=0)
```

Comment: Well... functions *can* have and *do* have members than are accessible if you use then as first-class objects without calling them :)